# Keystrokes command doesn't work on RDP Sessions

Tags: automationanywhere

When I schedule a task, the Keystroke commands doesn't work, other commands like Object clonning, Log to file works fine, but Keystroke do not work.

Each Keystroke has identified the window where it should be executed. I do not know what it could be. Any Idea?

The AA version is 10.5

Comment: I don't know AA at all, but windows is notoriously evil when it comes to native event automation on remote systems. Run the task as an administrator, disable UAC, make sure the console session is open (no screen lock timeout), If the system restarts now and then make sure that autologon is configured. Also for newer windows you'll need a scheduled task that sends the session back to the console with tscon when an RDP session disconnects to maintain a persistent console session.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you're being limited by Windows UAC (User Access Control) and DEP (Data Execution Prevention). Please see AA's documentation [here](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/customizing-an-automation-client/setting-user-access-control.html) for their suggestions on these two items.